# Need to dump mysql triggers

Tags: mysql

I have to dump triggers from production to local server. Is there some way to dump it like a sql?

i need something like this:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS triggername; 
CREATE TRIGGER triggername 
AFTER DELETE ON tablename 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
body of trigger;
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for myself not clear but it works.

I just created query:

```
select CONCAT("DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS ",t.TRIGGER_NAME,"; CREATE TRIGGER ",t.TRIGGER_NAME," ",t.ACTION_TIMING," ",t.EVENT_MANIPULATION," ON ",t.EVENT_OBJECT_TABLE," FOR EACH ROW ",t.ACTION_STATEMENT,";") FROM information_schema.triggers t
```

this can by easily added to other machine.